# calling string as variable in python

Tags: python, string, variables

I created a class called SignalParam in python containing different properties (frequency, voltage, time, etc)

I would like to create many instances of this type

```
vars()['Segment'+str(segment_number)] = SignalParam()
```

this line is working and i can create variables "Segment1", "Segment2", ....

My question is: i would like to call those variabes like

```
"Segment"+segment_number.freqency=33
```

Comment: This seems better suited for a dictionary. Why not set the values with your key being a string constructed like you posted above? `my_dict["Segment"+segment_number.frequency] = 33`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably better to use a dictionary here. Define one with `segments = {}`. Then you can create a `SignalParam` by keying into your dictionary with your segment number:

```
segments[segment_number] = SignalParam()
```

and use the object like this:

```
segments[segment_number].frequency = 33
```

Answer (score 5):

This is bad style. Use a dictionary instead, and simple keys to access:

```
 d = {}
 d['Segment'+str(segment_number)] = SignalParam()
 d['Segment'+str(segment_number)].frequency = 33
```

The reason you shouldn't use `vars` is because it means you create global variables, which you should avoid. And given your access-style, you don't even need it.

Answer (score -1):

Not the most secure solution but you could use exec:

```
exec("Segment"+segment_number+".frequency=33")
```

Comment: It is better to forget that `exec` exists. In my +15 years of python, I found maybe 2.3 legit uses deep in meta-programming. It's like giving a toddler a gatling gun. No idea what it does, but it's funny revolving...

Comment: deets, do you have any links the legitimate uses? I'm intrigued, as a former toddler who no longer sees any use for the gattling gun.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh this is one I can remember: re-creating the signature of a decorated function so you get proper error-messages on them https://github.com/micheles/decorator/blob/master/src/decorator.py